# How to extend Venia theme rather than overriding it

Tags: pwa, pwa-studio, venia

In the latest version of PWA Studio most Venia components is separated to UI library.

See the git commit: https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/commit/fa0a4c9b45757c272f6b745c546e8b61b1da40db

What is the good approach to extend the venia theme ?

I have had a look at fallback studio but it seems out of date with the latest version 
https://github.com/Jordaneisenburger/fallback-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the most current work on the [develop branch](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio) you now have a folder called [venia-concept](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/tree/develop/packages/venia-concept), this is where all your custom work will go. Similar to a theme, but not exactly the same.

The pwa app is pointing to the [index.js](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/blob/develop/packages/venia-concept/src/index.js) file in `venia-concept` as it's entry point. The way you use this is to replace the call to `app` from `venia-ui` to `venia-concept`. You can just copy the whole `App` folder into `venia-concept` and update the index.js file like such:

```
import App, { AppContextProvider } from './components/App';
```

This now points to an app file that you have copied over.

> pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/src/components/App/app.js

You will need to update the `import` statements along the way as you add in more components to override. So in your app file you will have something like this:

```
import React, { Fragment, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { array, bool, func, shape, string } from 'prop-types';

import { HeadProvider, Title } from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/Head';
import Main from '../Main';
import Mask from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/Mask';
import MiniCart from '../MiniCart';
import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import renderRoutes from './renderRoutes';
import errorRecord from '@magento/peregrine/lib/util/createErrorRecord';
import ToastContainer from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/ToastContainer';
import Icon from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/Icon';
```

You can see that i'm now pointing to the local copy of Minicart in this file, it's no longer pointing to `venia-ui`. In case where you want to point to the core file, not your override, you use `import Mask from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/Mask';`

From here you can add in more and more components as you customize your shop.

Comment: Do you know how to extend/overwrite RootComponents ? E.G: `@magento/venia-ui/lib/RootComponents/Category/`

Comment: In the same manor, but the path is different: `pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/src/RootComponents/Category`. This way of doing overrides is going out of favor with newer updates to the project, so this might not work in all version of pwa studio.

Comment: Yeah, I've found out eventually thanks. What will be the next trend for overwriting do you you have any links or reference ?

Comment: I would recommend getting on the magneto dev slack channel and looking in the pwa room. https://gist.github.com/lorikrell/65b50774450b526bdea4780872d6df1d. But if i'm to guess, as they move the pwa project into npm packages, there will be more flexibility in overrides with the webpack config. But i haven't been working on a site with the latest release, so i can't say for sure.

Comment: Ok, cool no worries, I'm on the slack channel as well. Well you mention webpack config I'm actually overwriting components such as CategoryTree, ProductFullDetail etc... with a webpack config overwrite.

Comment: Since the files are copied over, is there a non-manual way to handle updates?